# Windows 10 security features "this app cant open" on arm64 insider preview build - M1 mac

Tags: windows, mac, virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-insider

I am trying to change my security virus & threat protection settings to allow for a certain download to get through (NOT A VIRUS). Every time I try to download it using chrome and edge it says "stopped - Virus Found". I went to settings searched for security and tried to click on Virus&Threat Protection however it shows "this app can't open". I have tested it with a windows 11 arm64 build too, the same result. here are my Virtual Machine specs, it is a UTM - Virtualized VM Using their windows 10+ preset. I have it using half my 4 core and half my 16GB ram on M1 Macbook pro. Link to the windows build im using: https://uupdump.net/selectedition.php?id=7811e991-621e-4b0c-a066-ee0d4b53eacf&pack=en-us

edit:
I am trying to download a lua injector for educational purposes. when i download it of course it is blocked for mailware. I tried to turn of the Virus And Threat Protection in Windows settings and This Pops up (Image Below):
[Image Of Error Message Recieved "This app can't open"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80aBk.png)

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: `Windows 12` does not exist so what version did you actually test?

Comment: @Ramhound windows 11 i meant

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.